what if an equation and an integral disagree in a system of differential equations?
This question is related to another question about adding a derivative to a system of differential equations. I'm trying to separate the two questions in that post.
I have a system of differential equations. The two relevant ones are these:
$$i' = \frac{v-ir-id'k_1}{ik_2}$$
$$d'' = i^2k_3M(d)$$
We're solving this numerically, so we'll introduce the equations:
$$D = d'$$
$$D'= i^2k_3M(d)$$
$$I = i'$$
$$I' = i''$$
The last two aren't that relevant to this question. But I've included them to be complete.
what $M(d)$ is exactly I don't think is relevant, but you can see it in my other question.
I'm trying to solve this numerically. So I want a function that given $U=<i,I,d,D,v>$ returns $dU=<i',I',d',D',v'>$. I used the equation $i' = \frac{v-ir-id'k_1}{ik_2}$ to get $i'$, and I'd like to also use it to get $d'$. So I rearranged to solve to $d'$. But this lead to errors that got me thinking seriously about what the heck is going on. It seems to me there is inherently a contradiction between this equation and the equation for $D'$ at many points in the slope space.
Consider initial values such as $i=0, I=0, d=0,D=0,v=200$. Obviously there is a singularity, and we would conclude that $d'$ is infinite. (or, very close to $i=0$, $d'$ gets arbitrarily large). But since $i=0$, we should also conclude that $D'=0$. See the problem? our initial conditions have $D=0$ and $D'=0$, so $D$ can't change at all in the next time step. But at the same time, our equation for $d'$ is infinite, so $d$ will be infinite in the next time step. $D$ and $d'$ are the same thing. We can't have that one is zero and the other is infinite. If you say, "well, $D$ is in the first time step, and $d'$ is in the second timestep", then I will reply this is not possible, especially when the rate at which $D$ is changing is zero!
It doesn't seem to help if we move our initial conditions off of the singularity. Consider $i=\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small. Then $d'$ is arbitrarily large, $D$ is still zero, and $D'$ is arbitrarily small.
What does it mean that using forward euler on $d''$ seems to result in a different number than solving one of my equations does?
Edit: turns out there is no singularity, because $v=-i/C$ and after substitution, the $i$ on the bottom cancels out. And in fact, it seems if I solved for $d'$ now, there is no contradiction. But I guess the question still remains, could you imagine such a system of differential equations, and what would it mean?

It usually means that you don't have uniqueness for solutions through $(D,D')=(0,0)$.  It can mean that the order of one or more of your differential equations depends on $D$ or $D'$, like $Dy'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = r(x)$ (see "singular equations"), so the solution behaviour changes suddenly at $D = 0$ or $D' = 0$.  You may need to study how the system changes as $(D,D') \rightarrow (0,0)$.
